# postgres docker error alter table offer_company_favorite drop constraint FKa9qoi1pliuiby09jipnl6xts6" via JDBC Statement

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, docker-compose

hi i have error alter table offer_company_favorite drop constraint FKa9qoi1pliuiby09jipnl6xts6" via JDBC Statement" when i started my docker-compose . this link of my project https://gitlab.com/MisterThomas/wesharejoblocal i only work for now with weShareJob-service-offer after i result i working authentication.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/offer
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs

server.port=8085

spring.devtools.restart.log-condition-evaluation-delta=false
```

this my classe offer_company_favorite

```
model offer

@Entity
@Table(name="offercompanyfavorites")
public class OfferCompanyFavorite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

variables

```
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "date_scrap_offer")
    private Date date_scrap_offer;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "is_active")
    private Boolean is_active;
```

forgein key

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "offercompany_id", nullable = true)
    private OfferCompany offercompany;
```

constructor

```
    @JsonCreator
    public OfferCompanyFavorite(String username, Date date_scrap_offer, Boolean is_active) {
        this.username = username;
        this.date_scrap_offer = date_scrap_offer;
        this.is_active = is_active;

    }


    public OfferCompanyFavorite(Long id,String username, Date date_scrap_offer, Boolean is_active) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.date_scrap_offer = date_scrap_offer;
        this.is_active = is_active;

    }


        public OfferCompanyFavorite(Long id,String username, Date date_scrap_offer, Boolean is_active,OfferCompany offercompany) {
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.date_scrap_offer = date_scrap_offer;
            this.is_active = is_active;
            this.offercompany = offercompany;
    
        }
```

getter ans setter

```
        public OfferCompanyFavorite() {
    
        }
    
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(final Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    
        public void setUsername(final String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    
        public Boolean getIs_active() {
            return is_active;
        }
    
        public void setIs_active(Boolean is_active) {
            this.is_active = is_active;
        }
    
        public OfferCompany getOffercompany() {
            return offercompany;
        }
    
        public void setOffercompany(final OfferCompany offercompany) {
            this.offercompany = offercompany;
        }
    
    
        public Date getDate_scrap_offer() {
            return date_scrap_offer;
        }
    
        public void setDate_scrap_offer(Date date_scrap_offer) {
            this.date_scrap_offer = date_scrap_offer;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OfferCompanyFavorite [" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", username=" + username +
                    ", date_scrap_offer=" + date_scrap_offer +
                    ", is_active=" + is_active +
                    ", offercompany=" + offercompany +
                    "]";
        }
    }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresdb
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=offer
    restart: unless-stopped
  # APP*****************************************
  offer:
    image: offer:latest
    container_name: offer
    expose:
      - 8085
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    links:
      - postgresdb
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

thanks for you help :)

Comment: I think you forgot to add the error message.

Comment: no its was in title andfrist text. it's okay i have resolve this problem :)